# Android AlarmManager: how to avoid to going off of past alarms

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager

Hi and thank you for your help.

I have an application that uses AlarmManager to set one alarm a day for the next weeks, months...

- I set one alarm for each day of the week to start the Activity

and

- one alarm for each day of the week for stopping the Activity after
  some time

I have the following problem that I will try to explain in the following lines:

Today is Wednesday,

I open the application and set my alarms for MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN...
as soon as I set the alarms:

ALL the alarms for MON and TUE go immediately off I end up with 4 instances of the Activity !!!!

Please how do I avoid this???

Please see a piece of my code:

```
        // SET THE ALARM FOR STARTING THE ACTIVITY 
        Intent smon = new Intent(ctxt, VideoActivty.class);
        smon.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent psmon = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, smon, 0);

        Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
        calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hsmon);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, msmon);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),
                7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, psmon);

        // SET THE ALARM FOR KILLING THE ACTIVITY 
        Intent fmon = new Intent(ctxt, VideoActivty.class);
        fmon.putExtra("finish", true);
        PendingIntent pfmon = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt, 0, fmon, 0);

        calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hfmon);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mfmon);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),
                7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pfmon);
```

This is the Activity:

```
public class VideoActivty extends Activity {
private VideoView video;
private MediaController ctlr;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
private KeyguardLock keyguard;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this
            .getSystemService(this.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    keyguard = km.newKeyguardLock("MyApp");
    keyguard.disableKeyguard();

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
    //if you want the controls to appear
    videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" 
    + R.raw.ingress); //do not add any extension
    //if your file is named sherif.mp4 and placed in /raw
    //use R.raw.sherif
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
    setContentView(videoHolder);

    videoHolder.start();
    videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        mp.start();
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent (Intent i){


  if( i.getBooleanExtra("finish",false) ){
      wl.release();
      keyguard.reenableKeyguard();
      finish();
  }
}


}
```

Answer (score 5):

As the API page of [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) states regarding the *set(...)* and *setRepeating(...)* methods:

> "If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be
>   triggered immediately, with an alarm count depending on how far in the
>   past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval."

So, if for example you are on Wednesday, then the AlarmManager will fire the events of: Sunday, Monday, Tuesday and (possibly) Wednesday. It will actually fire only one for all of them.

Here is how I avoid this. Not sure it is the best way, but it works smoothly.

Let's say that you store the **day of the week**, the **hour** and the **minute** of the day in which you want to fire your AlarmManager in the following variables:

```
final int myAlarmDayOfTheWeek = ...;
final int myAlarmHour = ...;
final int myAlarmMinute = ...;
```

Of course, here I'm assuming you store the **day of the week** with the same convention of the [Calendar class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html), i.e.:

> Sunday = Calendar.SUNDAY = 1
>
> Monday = Calendar.MONDAY = 2
>
> ... ... ...
>
> Saturday = Calendar.SATURDAY = 7

Then:

```
Calendar timestamp = Calendar.getInstance();

//Check whether the day of the week was earlier in the week:
if( myAlarmDayOfTheWeek > timestamp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) ) {
    //Set the day of the AlarmManager:
    time.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (myAlarmDayOfTheWeek - timestamp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));
}
else {
    if( myAlarmDayOfTheWeek < timestamp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) ) {
        //Set the day of the AlarmManager:
        timestamp.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (7 - (timestamp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - myAlarmDayOfTheWeek)));
    }
    else {  // myAlarmDayOfTheWeek == time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        //Check whether the time has already gone:
        if ( (myAlarmHour < timestamp.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) || ((myAlarmHour == timestamp.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) && (myAlarmMinute < timestamp.get(Calendar.MINUTE))) ) {
            //Set the day of the AlarmManager:
            timestamp.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
        }
    }
}

//Set the time of the AlarmManager:
timestamp.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, myAlarmHour);
timestamp.set(Calendar.MINUTE, myAlarmMinute);
timestamp.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Note that by using [Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR) in the [Calendar.add(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29), you don't even need to take care of the change of the month...

If you are in the first condition (i.e. myAlarmDayOfTheWeek > timestamp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), you can also just use [Calendar.set(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int%29) with [Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) as field and *myAlarmDayOfTheWeek* as value.

Now, you just need to setup your AlarmManager. For example:

```
final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timestamp.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, myAlarmPendingIntent);
```

Please, also avoid calculating the day interval (i.e. 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) every time, but use [AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_DAY) (or at most *86400000*) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Do we have a solution here ? I am still looking for solution, my code as below..

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,getweekday(obj));
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timepicker.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timepicker.getCurrentMinute());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    if(calendar.before(cal_now)){//if its in the past increment
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    }

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),_id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, sender);
```

Answer (score 1):

From AlarmManager

> int    RTC_WAKE Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall clock time in UTC), which will wake up the device when it goes off.`

From Calendar

> Calendar.getInstance()
>
> a Calendar subclass instance set to the current date and time in the default Timezone.

Those two use will different time zones.

Also by changing only `DAY_OF_WEEK` you are not changing `WEEK_OF_YEAR` field of a Calendar object. Meaning that if it is Wed but you are setting up an alarm for Mon (by changing only day of week) it will go off immediately as it is set for the Mon of this week. If you need to set the alarms for every day of the week at the same hour

```
    alarmManager(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (24hoursOfMilliseconds), 24hoursOfMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
```

This will set up the very same alarm, repeating every 24h. If you need to do different things on different days just use

```
switch(calendarObj.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) { }
```

Comment: thanks!!! But I am not sure I understand... please how can I fix this? Thank you very much. Lisa

Comment: UTC is GMT. If you are anywhere west of London, you're in the past. Change timezone on your `Calendar` object to UTC as required.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll do that. It's just a bit counter-intuitive, because this happens even if today is Wednesday and the alarm is set for Monday !

Comment: but a different day in the month of July in year 2013, sorry I still don't get it. Thanks Anyway

Comment: @LisaAnne Say you get the instance of the Calendar for 5th week of the year and it's wWed. Now when you set `DAY_OF_WEEK` to Monday. It's still 5th week of the year. Edited once more.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but problem is not solved... Thank you anyway!

Comment: please why do you use  "+ weekWorthOfMilliseconds" ? thanks anyway... Lisa

Comment: The first parameter is the initial launch time. The first time it should get launched. By offsetting it by that amount(if I understood right a week) you can get the calendar object for the current week, change the day of the week to the desired one, but it will not go off until a week has passed. By the way be sure to use the static fields of Calendar for days of the week. [They are not numbered as you may think they are](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#WEDNESDAY)

Comment: So using "+ weekWorthOfMilliseconds" I miss the current week, right? Which is not what I want... still very confused

Comment: Either change both `DAY_OF_WEEK` and `WEEK_OF_YEAR` or `DAY_OF_YEAR` alone.

Comment: @JoelBodega everything above the first "edit" is barely understandable. Could you also please use the quote symbol ">" and not the "`" code symbol when you quote, if you quote... as I said, barely understandable....

Answer (score 0):

Just register today's date in shared preference with boolean and make it true when it will be executed for the first time. During restart if the notification is already delivered then ignore else notify the user. On next day just delete old preference and create new sharedpreference value

```
public boolean isAlreadyWished(String date,String previousDate){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if(sharedPref.contains(alreadyNotifiedString+previousDate)){
        sharedPref.edit().remove(alreadyNotifiedString+previousDate);
    }
    if(sharedPref.contains(alreadyNotifiedString+date)){
        boolean displayOrderString = sharedPref.getBoolean(alreadyNotifiedString+date, false);
        return  displayOrderString;
    }else{
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(alreadyNotifiedString+date,true);
        return  false;
    }

}
```