# Why alarm notification isn't showing up?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In my alarmclock project, I have added `pendingIntent`. I want that when the alarm fires, it should be able to pop up a notification message (so that user knows the alarm is triggering) even if the application is closed/minimized/or the device is idle. But this isn't happening in my case even though I have `ComponentName`. At this moment, to stop alarm, I have to open the app again and OFF the toggle button. ***(1)*** ***How could I solve it?***

As I said, once the app is closed/ or minimized, I need to reopen the app to stop alarm. But if I press the toggle button to stop, it doesn't stop the alarm. The more I toggle, the more it loops through the same ringtone and speeds up the tone, that is very very wired. ***(2) Why it's happening and how can I solve it?*** *[NOTE: It doesn't occur when the app is already open, this only happens when I close/minimize/or go back.]*

I have used `set` method. The problem with this is the alarm can also trigger in the past time set. But, this something I defenitely don't want. ***(3) What can be an alternative method for `set()` that can solve this issue?***

[P.S.  I KNOW THIS IS SUCH A BIG POST, CAN BE IRRITATING FOR SOMEONE. MY HUMBLE REQUEST, DON'T COMMENT NEGATIVE OR DOWNVOTE MY POST. IF YOU REALLY DON'T LIKE MY IT AND DON'T WANT TO TAKE ANY STEP TO HELP ME, SIMPLY JUST AVOID THE POST.I AM GETTING SO MUCH FRUSTRATION AND DIPRESSION WITH THIS ALARM CLOCK APP.]

MainActivity:

```
package com.mycompany.alarmclock;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
//imported stuff isn't shown here.
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;//an action to be performed by other/foreign application
    private TimePicker alarmTimePicker;//In where the user set the time
    private static MainActivity inst;
    private TextView alarmTextView;//the area where alarm message/notification will be displayed


    public static MainActivity instance() {
        return inst;
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        inst = this;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
        alarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmText);
        ToggleButton alarmToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    }


    public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
        if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {//if toggle button is "ON" do the alarming function
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Alarm On");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        } else {
            AlarmReceiver.stopRingtone();
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            setAlarmText("");
            Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
        }

    }

    public void setAlarmText(String alarmText) {
        alarmTextView.setText(alarmText);

    }

}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
    package com.mycompany.alarmclock;

import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
//Imported stuff isn't shown here
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static Ringtone mRingtone=null;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        MainActivity inst=MainActivity.instance();
        inst.setAlarmText("\n                  Alarm!\n           Get Up! Get up!");
        Uri alarmUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

        if (alarmUri == null) {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        mRingtone=RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context,alarmUri);
        mRingtone.play();
        //ringtone.play();

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                AlarmService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
    public  static void stopRingtone(){
        mRingtone.stop();
    }
}
```

AlarmService:

```
    package com.mycompany.alarmclock;
//imported stuff isn't shown here.
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

private NotificationManager alarmnotificationManager;

    public AlarmService(){
        super("AlarmService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        sendNotification("Get up! Get up!");

    }
    private void sendNotification(String msg){

        Log.d("AlarmService","Sending notification...:"+msg);
        alarmnotificationManager=(NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);


        alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        alarmnotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
        Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");

    }

}
```

activity_mail.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#deb887">



    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/alarmTimePicker"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#8ffdba" />


    <ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Alarm On/Off"
    android:id="@+id/alarmToggle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/alarmTimePicker"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
        android:checked="false"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="#f3f6ff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/alarmText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alarmToggle"
        android:background="#0e8146"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Share On Facebook"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#3B5998"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:shadowColor="#b0e0e6"
        android:textColor="#00ff80"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.alarmclock" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>


    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_updated"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

UPDATE:
LOG:

```
  03-23 15:28:46.372    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1321)
03-23 15:28:46.548    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
03-23 15:28:46.548    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7ddaf88, tid 1474
03-23 15:28:46.560    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
03-23 15:28:46.560    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
03-23 15:28:46.604    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-23 15:28:46.608    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
03-23 15:28:46.608    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
03-23 15:28:46.616    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
03-23 15:28:46.616    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
03-23 15:28:46.616    1474-1474/com.mycompany.alarmclock D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: First let me ask a silly naive question. Is the onReceive method gets called and executed?  I will try to solve the annoying bug #2 even though I never used AlarmManager. Now maybe...I will learn about it.

Comment: Oh...pls change the wording "wired" to "weird" before I get weirded out or too wired :-)

Comment: Riyana, How is this problem going? Is problem #2 solved yet? Next time for you, you may email me if/when you have a new post.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 and question 3 could possibly be solved by using `setExact()` instead of `set()`, and using `RTC_WAKEUP` instead of `RTC`.

See documentation for  [setExact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and [RTC_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP).

Regarding alarms set in the past, this is by design for `set()`.

The documentation states:

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately. If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the equality of two intents being defined by filterEquals(Intent)), then it will be removed and replaced by this one.

Also see this post: [Android AlarmManager: how to avoid to going off of past alarms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576292/android-alarmmanager-how-to-avoid-to-going-off-of-past-alarms/20999784#20999784)

Now, for your biggest issue, question 2, it looks like it's being caused because you don't have the `Intent` and `PendingIntent` set up for properly canceling the alarm if the app has been closed and re-opened.

In addition, you might want to add `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` as an extra failsafe to prevent multiple alarms from being scheduled.

See code below:

```
 public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
        if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {//if toggle button is "ON" do the alarming function
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Alarm On");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        } else {
            AlarmReceiver.stopRingtone();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            setAlarmText("");
            Log.d("MyActivity", "Alarm Off");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Daniel Nugent, ur answer is very admirable, i appreciate your time taking. But unfortunately it doen't work. Changing the code according to your suggestion doesn't take any effect. Surprisingly the app behaves in the similar way.

Comment: @Riyana, that is puzzling.  If possible, please run your app and post your resulting logs in your question.  I can take a look and see if there is anything from the logs that can determine where the problem is happening.

Comment: Strage, I don't see any `Alarm On` or `Alarm Off` logs.  Is it possible that there is more if you let it run for longer, or go into the app and toggle the alarm?

Answer (score 1):

I want to assist you in issue #2. I believe you said the toggle button works to start and stop the Alarm timer. But it does not work when you close or minimize, which I call it "undoing the backstack" to return to the screen. I hope I got the issue correct.

Now...I don't like (not comfortable) where you place the `new Intent` because the Pending Intent may lose its original context, I believe. So place/move these codes below into the **OnCreate** from onToggleClicked(), perhaps on the bottom is fine:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

My main concern is that I want to make sure object **pendingIntent** is the same when you cancel(), the one coming from set(). To be clear, the codes above should not be in onToggleClicked anymore, my suggestion.

Comment: no, not fixed yet. Actually I gave up with this one and continuing to another project....I think there is a GHOST in my code that is preventing to work it properly (Joke!)

Comment: Perhaps the Ghost is another AlarmReceiver service, haha.